# What do i use for names and id in forms with repeated rows

Tags: javascript, forms, xhtml

I'm programming an order form that has multiple order items. Each line item is a  row in form, identical to the previous row. I'm wondering what the convention for names and ids on the input fields. Do i use the same names and id for the fields in each row?

How do I reference an input field within a particular form row?

How do i reference the rows of the form as an array?

What's the best programming approach?

for example:

item quantity item_price total_price
item quantity item_price total_price
item quantity item_price total_price

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually add the line number before/after it so that if I need reference it for AJAX and such, it has a unique name.

Comment: do you add the line number to each id or as a separate hidden field on each row?

Comment: To each id, so for row 1 you'd have item1 quantity1 item_price1 total_price1.  Looping on them can then be done using getElementById('item' + i)  where i is the incrementing number.

Comment: Having an id start with a number violates the w3c spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2